# AWS Lightsail terminal blocked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I installed WordPress on AWS Lightsail following aws’ video tutorial. Generated a static IP and watched the WP site running on the browser. To log into WP I have the user and have to retrieve the password using the terminal. To launch it I clicked the “Connect with SSH” button and a terminal pop-out. Unfortunately the terminal is blocked/freezed and I can’t write any command nor click into it. Restarted the instance and tried 4 browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari) and nothing works.
I completely deleted the instance and created a new one but have the same problem. 
Anyone know what’s happening and how to make the terminal work? Is there other way to get the wP password I need? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser terminal interface can be problematic. It is better to use an SSH client (such as PuTTY). You will need the private key to do this (see instructions if you don't have this). The official bitnami instructions can be found here

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/get-started-wordpress-aws-marketplace-intermediate/

If you don't have the WordPress password, these can be found in the initial installation logs, or in /home/bitnami/bitnami_credientials. Refer to Step 4 of the instructions

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/get-started-marketplace/

Hope this helps.